# captureVideo broken windows phone - phonegap

Tags: html, cordova, windows-phone, visual-studio-cordova

I am using the [official phonegap plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html)

Basically I am creating a folder in my isolated Storage and putting in there my 
uri file (the result is something like this: /CapturedImagesCache/WP_20150423_013.jpg and I can see the folder and the file with windows Power Tool)

While it works with the photo and I can set my  tag this way:

```
  var image = document.getElementById('img1');
            console.log("imageData: " + path);
            image.src = path;
```

The same does not work with the video, I am still getting the uri of the file and creating it in my isolated but after setting up my  only a message "Invalid Source" is displayed.

Why does it happen?

Is there anyone who used it before on windows phone?

Here is the source code of the plugin [github](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture/tree/master/src/wp/UI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is an issue for windows phone 8.1. Seems the local video cannot be accessed within webbrowser control which is used by cordova for windows 8 and windows 8.1 silverlight app. Here the link on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7fa66cbf-d67e-4c0a-bf2e-56262248d8df/set-video-to-html-video-tag-cordova-app?forum=ToolsForApacheCordova).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to set the src of an image instead of video.

If you try it with a video element, it should work.

js:

```
    var video = document.getElementById('vid');
    video.src = mediaFiles[0].fullPath;
    video.play();
```

html

```
<video id="vid"></video>
```

Comment: Thanks Murat, but see my comment below

Comment: I've looked at your project which you've provided on MSDN and seems like you're using WP8. I was under the impression that you were using 8.1. This is actually a supported scenario on 8.1 WWA. Hope it helps, thanks